# Initialize jquery plugin on page load angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, plugins, angular5

So i am using jquery-filer for file upload in my angular 5 app. Everything works well but the plugin only displays properly after page reload, so unless the user reloads the page they will still see the default selectfile button.

> index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.single-file').filer();
  $('.multi-file').filer();
</script>
```

> component.ts

```
<label>Other Images</label>
<input type="file" name="other_images" class="multi-file form-control"
[(ngModel)]="product.other_images"
[formControl]="productForm.controls['otherImages']" multiple (change)="addOtherDocuments($event)" />
```

on page load this is what i get

[image]

after reload it displays properly

[image]

what is the better for this to shows properly on initial page load

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Put it in your componnent's ngOnInit method

Comment: @David i did that and same thing

Comment: try in `ngAfterViewInit` instead.  If it still does not work, can you maybe show an examle on stackblitz.com?

Comment: whoa, been searching google for a solution never knew of this. solved it adding to ngAfterViewInit in my component. Thanks @David